# how configure setting for kafka to delete messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, clj-kafka

I'm using Kafka (with Yahoo Kafka manager)

I want to set a rule for resetting messages or how they call it : "Sum of partition offsets"

Is there any parameter of rolling the kafka offsets at server.properties?

(i.e: I want to reset or delete all the params that are affecting message retention)

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean set a rule for resetting the messages?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change a topics retention policy by changing default values after topic creation. Delete retention is per topic and if not given when created, uses default values.

If you want to change topic retention policy on the fly, you can use command below;

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper your_server_ip:2181 --alter --topic your_topic_name --config retention.ms=604800000
```

This will take couple minutes to effect.